# Elastic search grouping by nested field and ordering by sum of _score of parent match

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "documents":{
    "mappings":{
        "document":{
            "dynamic":"strict",
            "_all":{
                "enabled":false
            },
            "properties":{
                "authors":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "properties":{

                        "authorId":{
                            "type":"long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "docId":{
                    "type":"long"
                },
                "clusters":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "analyzer":"whitespace",
                    "similarity":"BM25"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A single author can write multiple documents.
I am trying to group by `authorId` and order by sum of the `_scores` of matching parent document i.e the  author ids should be in the descending order of the sums of the matching `_score` of the parent document of which this author was a nested field. The below query doesn't return the expected results. What am I doing wrong

```
"size":0
    "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [

            { "match": { 

                "clusters":{
                    "query":  "sports"                    
               }
            }
           },
           { "match": { 

                "clusters":{
                    "query":  "politics"                   
               }
            }
           }


        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
     "group_by_authorId": {
         "nested":{
          "path": "authors"
         },
         "aggs" :{
           "top_authors":{
               "terms":{
                 "field": "authors.authorId",
                 "order": {
                     "max_score": "desc"
                 }
               },
               "aggs":{
                   "max_score": {
                        "sum": {
                            "script":"_score"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: could you provide some sample documents? also if one author is related with multiple documents, don't you think documents should be `nested` object and not authors? or it could be vice-versa? could you explain the reason behind making authors `nested`?